# OkHttp 3 для Новичков

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Всем привет. Недавно начал изучать Java под андроид и много вопросов возникло. Одно из них то, что я не могу понять как с помощью OkHttp3 библиотеки отправить пост запрос. Простой пост без json. Если есть примеры, учебники и т.д. хотелось бы почитать.

Comment: Смотрели документацию либы? Там, вроде, был пример.

Comment: Смотрел и не понял как Пост отправить? Как взять ответ? там Было но на английском не очень то понял

Comment: Куда именно смотрели?

Comment: свой сайт точный адресс не помню но чтото типа square/okhttp  или square/github/okhttp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
//через клиент шлём запрос
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
//в formBody кладём параметры запроса
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("message", "Your message")
        .build();
//создаём запрос, указывая адрес и параметры
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://www.foo.bar/index.php")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

//исполняем запрос синхронно, в том потоке, в коем вызываем `execute`
try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    String serverAnswer = response.body().string();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//исполняем запрос асинхронно
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
        //ВАЖНО! Тут не главный поток, менять UI отсюда нельзя, надо на UI-поток переключаться
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        //ВАЖНО! Тут не главный поток, менять UI отсюда нельзя, надо на UI-поток переключаться
        String serverAnswer = response.body().string();
    }
});
```

Comment: А для пост запроса что нужно написать?

Comment: Это и есть пост запрос.

Comment: Принимаю их в пхп. Принимать как простой $_POST или как json

Comment: По идее первое, пост с параметрами.

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: последний вопрос в formBody параметры можно добавлять бесконечное количество add ()

Comment: @user8978194, если ограничение и есть, то оно лежит где-то после 65 000. Думаю, можно этим пренебречь и считать, что да - бесконечное количество.

Comment: Хехе. Спасибо))