# В чом проблема отправки запроса

Tags: android, kotlin, http, requests, get

код:

```
val url = URL("https://api.exchangerate.host/latest").openConnection()
            BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(url.getInputStream())).use { inp ->
                var line: String?
                while (inp.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                    println(line)
                }
            }
```

ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.converter/com.example.converter.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Comment: Вот, почитайте: [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/506131/384202)

Comment: я не очень понимаю как мне это обьединить, не могли бы вы привести пример конкретный с запросом и ассинхронной задачей

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/759231/17609